# Changing Label in toolbar using wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I currently have a toolbar in wxpython with an start icon. I want it so when this icon is clicked the icon and method that it uses changes to stop.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
logClient2.py    
Created by Allister on 2010-11-30.
"""

import wx
import sqlite3

WINDOW_SIZE = (900,400)

class logClient(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=WINDOW_SIZE)        

        self.toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
        self.toolbar.AddLabelTool(1, 'Refresh', wx.Bitmap('icons/refresh_icon.png'))
        self.toolbar.Realize()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.startLiveUpdate, id=1)

        self.Show(True)

    def startLiveUpdate(self, event):
      pass  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    logClient(None, -1, "Log Event Viewer")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Not really sure what to put in the startLiveUpdate method ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quickly hacked together one. Tested on Ubuntu 9.10, Python 2.6, wx 2.8.10.1

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
logClient2.py    
Created by Allister on 2010-11-30.
"""

import wx
import sqlite3

WINDOW_SIZE = (900,400)

class logClient(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=WINDOW_SIZE)        

        self.toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
        self.startLiveUpdate(None)

        self.Show(True)

    def startLiveUpdate(self, event):
        self.createToolbarItem("Refresh", "refresh.jpg", self.stopLiveUpdate)

    def stopLiveUpdate(self, event):
        self.createToolbarItem("Stop", "refresh2.jpg", self.startLiveUpdate)


    def createToolbarItem(self, label, imageName, method):
        self.toolbar.RemoveTool(1)
        self.toolbar.AddLabelTool(1, label, wx.Bitmap(imageName))
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, method, id=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    logClient(None, -1, "Log Event Viewer")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: but in the case where there are more buttons on toolbar, this trick don't preserve the order and adds to the last.. any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less hacked version than the accepted answer for wxpython 4.x

```
self.tool = self.toolbar.AddTool(-1, "A tool", "image.png")
```

...

```
def change_tool_label(self):
    self.tool.SetLabel("A new label")
    # need to call Realize() to re-draw the toolbar
    self.toolbar.Realize()
```